# How to do if-statement for a three type user login?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a log in system which I'm working on right now. It has a two type user Login working but now I'm trying to add a third type user "Judge User" but I'm having trouble with "if statements". 
The part where it redirects to location accordingly to the user type it should go to "login_judge.php" but I can't seem to work the extra "if".

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { 

        $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
        if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Success";
            header('location: login_admin.php');
        }else{
            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Success";
            header('location: login_user.php');
         }else {
        array_push($errors, "User and Password don't match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to test each $logged_in_user['user_type'] value. At the moment you allow 2 types of login admin and everyone else.

Comment: Both user and admin logins work, I'm having trouble making the third type work.

Comment: You need an else if: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Thank you so much for that link, I didn't know about "elseif". It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful!

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

    $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
        $_SESSION['success']  = "Success";
        header('location: login_admin.php');
    } elseif($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'Judge User') {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
        $_SESSION['success']  = "Success";
        header('location: login_judge.php');
    } elseif($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'user') {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
        $_SESSION['success']  = "Success";
        header('location: login_user.php');
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "User and Password don't match");
    }

}
```

Comment: I need a third user type, both user and admin are working

Comment: Define all the User Type's for ex. Admin, Judge User, User and use elseif in PHP so you can use multiple statements! Updated the code tho!